AWS Appsync Data Source and Web Identities
So, I have a setup composed by cognito, appsync and dynamoDB. Users authenticate through Cognito, where through claims they assume an IAM role given by the group they're in (let's call this company_role). This role has the following trust relationship:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:6a6c6ae0-5c94-4cb4-b31c-d56dc55116ab"
            }
        }
    }
]

}
Using this role, users invoke an AppSync (with a DynamoDB data source) Endpoint and I'm able to verify that if the role company_role doesn't have permission to invoke appsync nothing works (as intended).
However, the problem is that I also want to use company_role to control which records from DynamoDB the invoking users can see. But I was able to verify that instead of company_role, access control to DynamoDB is controlled by the role associated to the AppSync Data source.
Is there a way to carry over the user group role all the way from Appsync, through the Data source, to dynamo to control access there?
